# Antialiasing on shadows in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am going through tutorials on the net trying to learn libgdx (so far I am amazed at how powerful it is) and I am trying to figure out how I can make the shadows render with soft edges, they are blocky, especially noticeable with multiple lightsources that overlap. The picture below demonstrates what I mean. [image]

This is with high raycounts

```
new PointLight(handler, 5000, Color.GREEN, 80, width, height);
    new PointLight(handler, 5000, new Color(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 1), 200,
            width / 2, height / 2);
    new ConeLight(handler, 5000, new Color(0.9f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1), 200,
            width / 2, height, 0, 117);
```

and `cfg.useGL20 = true;`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, searched on google and found this. So I'll just answer it. The trick is to overload default RayHandler fbo size:

From:

```
handler = new RayHandler(world);
```

To:

```
handler = new RayHandler(world, width, height);
```